# Dynamic logical expression parser/evaluation in Java/Apex

Tags: java, parsing, logical-operators, apex, expression-evaluation

End-user can define condition selections/logical expressions in String like below:

- `String expression = "((1 OR 2) AND 6 AND (3 OR 4)) AND 5";`
- or `String expression = "(1 AND 2 AND 3 AND 4) OR (5 AND 6)";`
- or etc...

and the values of 1, 2, 3, ... are pre-calculated stored in a map like `{1: true, 2: false, 3: true, ...}`

The requirement is to evaluate the above expression with the values stored in the map and get the final output in true/false.

For eg.:

```java
String expression = "(1 AND 2) OR 3";
Map<Integer, Boolean> values = new Map<Integer, Boolean>{1=> true, 2=> false, 3=> true};
System.debug(evaluate(expression, values)); // This should print true
```

In the above example "(1 AND 2) OR 3" should evaluates to "(true AND false) OR true", which result in final true answer.

**I need help in writing the `evaluate` method.**

Comment: See my SO article on how to write a recursive descent parser, then produces an (expession) tree.  It has additional parts that tell you have to evaluate an expression instead of producing the expression tree.   https://stackoverflow.com/a/2336769/120163

Comment: `System.out.println(new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("javascript").eval(Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(expression.replace("AND", "&&").replace("OR", "||")).replaceAll(m -> String.valueOf(values.get(Integer.parseInt(m.group()))))));`

Comment: @shmosel that's a terrible idea. That's how you get remote code execution. Don't use JS for something this simple and also don't do it in one line

Comment: @Clashsoft I know, I just hate squeezing multiple statements into a one-line comment.

Answer (score 0):

I covered such problems by embedding [Apache Jexl](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/).
Otherwise if you want to create your own parser go for [Antlr](https://www.antlr.org/) - it likely has a ready to use example for you.